# R: automate model selection

Tags: r, glm

I am using the step function to find best logistic model. I then have to copy and paste that model into a new call to glm.  Is there a way I can automate to generalize this?

```
full=glm(RESPONSE ~ SEX + TOTCHOL + ..., data=training,   
family=binomial(link="logit"))
summary(full)
anova(full,test="Chisq")

#BEST MODEL
full.forward <- step(null,   
                scope=list(lower=null,upper=full),direction="forward", 
                family=binomial(link="logit")

#rerun BEST MODEL getting details. I want the model automated.
reduced=glm(RESPONSE ~ SYSBP + as.factor(BPMEDS) + DIABP + BMI + AGE,
        data=training,family=binomial(link="logit"))
```

Mary A. Marion

Comment: Stepwise regression mostly gives you garbage: http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/20856/11849

Comment: You shouldn't rely on `step` to find the "best" model. Any into to regression analysis textbook will tell you that.

Comment: Your formula is stored in full.foward$terms. You can reuse it in the call to glm. But @Jon is right, step is not a great solution for what you want

Comment: All of your comments were great. I am using forward selection on purpose. Pauline what I am looking for is a way to extract only the model variables. I then want to put +'s between them so I have the right hand side of a logistic regression equation. That is where I am going with this.  Mary